# Any way to know what causes allocation of wired memory?

Tags: macos, memory

Activity Monitor lets me see how much memory is allocated as "wired", but I can't find a way to break the allocation down by applications or other memory consumers.

Is there a tool out there that lets me get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a webpage which has this definition](http://sg80bab.blogspot.com/2007/03/is-my-mac-using-too-much-memory.html) for wired memory:

> Wired memory is used by the OS and is pretty much untouchable. Another
>   application can't "borrow" wired memory

If you want to know more about how applications and frameworks are using memory on your system, try `/usr/bin/allmemory`. You must run it as root; `sudo /usr/bin/allmemory` is one way to accomplish that. When you run it, it will perform analysis for several seconds before showing output.

Here is a short example of the output:

```
                           Process Name [ PID]  Architecture    PrivateRes/NoSpec   Copied    Dirty    Swapped   Shared/NoSpec
                           ===================  ============    ================= ========= ========= =========  =============

                             WebProcess [ 317]:    64-bit        74126  /   73588      2102     48868       403  32777 / 30757
                                  Xcode [ 368]:    64-bit        55780  /   55711     25228     45570       595  43660 / 41720
                                 Safari [ 315]:    64-bit        25087  /   25087      2251     17647        52  35197 / 33513
```

See the allmemory man page (with the command `man allmemory`) for more details; here's an explanation of some of the columns:

PrivateRes: the number of pages resident in physical memory, not shared with other processes

Copied/Dirty: the number of resident pages that were copied or are dirty (non-exclusive)

Swapped: the number of pages that were in memory but have been swapped to disk.

Shared: the number of shared pages

Comment: Very useful, thanks! The swapped-out pages was another piece of information I had been looking for.

Comment: “wired” memory is not specifically memory used by the OS, but rather memory that has been “locked” into RAM with `mlock()` or something similar. `mlock()`ed memory cannot be swapped out to the hard drive. _Usually_ locked memory will belong to the OS, but this is not guaranteed at all. You can write a program that allocates and locks a chunk of memory for itself, no problem. I imagine this might be practical for storing passwords or other sensitive information to prevent traces being left on disk. (No downvote for this; it's not related to the actual question, and it's not terribly important.)